# Java log4j return some warnings

Tags: java, log4j

I am using `org.apache.log4j`

My log4j.properties file content is given below

```
log=D:\\logs
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n

log4j.appender.successLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.successLog.File=${log}\\success_log_${current.date}
log4j.appender.successLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.successLog.Append=false
log4j.appender.successLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n

log4j.appender.errorLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.errorLog.File=${log}\\error_log_${current.date}
log4j.appender.errorLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorLog.Append=false
log4j.appender.errorLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %m%n

log4j.category.successLogger=DEBUG, successLog
log4j.additivity.successLogger=false

log4j.category.errorLogger=DEBUG, errorLog
log4j.additivity.errorLogger=false
```

When I run this it run properly but it gives me the below Warnings

```
log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [FILE].
log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified which file the logs should be written to for `FILE` Logger.
Please specify below property to avoid this warning:

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=path-to-log-file
```

Comment: I already gives the file path for log file `log4j.appender.successLog.File=${log}\\success_log_${current.date}` and it is working.

Comment: In your case the logger is referred as `FILE` not `successLog`. There is no logger defined as `successLog` in your configuration.